# Polar Chart displaying as line chart?

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I am trying to create polar spider chart but it is displaying it as line graph.
I am doing it via making ajax calls.I have set these properties.

```
              chart=new {

                    polar = true,
                    type = "line"
                },
                title = new
                {
                    text = project
                },
                xAxis = new
                {
                    categories = pivotvalues,
                    tickmarkPlacement = "on",
                    lineWidth = 0
                },
                yAxis = new
                {
                    gridLineInterpolation = "polygon",
                    lineWidth = 0,
                    min =0
                },
```

I am populating the data for series from my database. It is showing as a line graph instead of polar-spider. Any suggestions?
I am loading the scripts in following order as well.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion where i might be doing it wrong?

Comment: I'd guess that `polar = true` should be inside a `chart` object, not the root.

Comment: I tried setting polar = true inside the .js file. it changed from line graph to a different one. Like this one but without the (blue line) data. Somehow it does not recognize the data. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rovLhf9c/

When i try to hard code the polar-web in my .cshtml it works though.

Comment: You haven't shown your data in your question.